# Sending Password over HTTPS - The Only Option?

Tags: json, security, hash, bcrypt

I've built a Rest API with node. Looking at the authentication route, I have passwords that are stored hashed using bcrypt.

Now when a user comes to login, I can hash the password client side, send this to the API however as far i can see it is not possible to compare 2 hashes. So does this mean the only secure option is to send it as plain text through HTTPS?

I've seen it answered here [Client side password hash versus plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723211/client-side-password-hash-versus-plain-text) however is there a general consensus plain text over https is the only significant way.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want to use HTTPS, you can use HTTP Digest Authentication

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely, positively must use HTTPS regardless of whether you computations client side or server side.  So if your goal is to remove the HTTPS and use HTTP instead: do not do it -- it opens the door to "pass the hash" attacks.

There are good arguments to move the bcrypt computation to the client side, but there a number of pitfalls that you must worry about to do it correctly.  For reference, see [Method to Protect Passwords in Databases for Web Applications](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/387.pdf) and [Client-Plus-Server Password Hashing as a Potential Way to Improve Security Against Brute Force Attacks without Overloading the Server](http://ithare.com/client-plus-server-password-hashing-as-a-potential-way-to-improve-security-against-brute-force-attacks-without-overloading-server/).  Two different solutions based upon similar ideas and observations.